✖ Unable to load package information from registry: The "timeout" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('100000')
I'm getting this error while installing pwa using ng add @angular/pwa.
the Error is

✖ Unable to load package information from registry: The "timeout"
argument must be of type number. Received type string ('100000')

the version I'm using is:
Angular CLI: 17.2.2
Node: 18.13.0
Package Manager: npm 8.19.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 17.2.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1703.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.3.5
@angular-devkit/core            17.3.7
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.3.7
@angular/cli                    17.2.2
@schematics/angular             17.3.7
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.3.3
zone.js                         0.14.4

